# How to iterate through a array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi everyone I just started learning js. One of the assignment is to add all firstname from a list of students to an array.
When I tried the following codes

```
    let students = [
    {
        fname: "Jam",
        lname: "Brazier",
        snum: "0010",

    },
    {
        fname: "Ricardo",
        lname: "Allen",
        snum: "0020",

    }]
```

and running

```
    for (let student in students) {
    console.log(student.fname);
}
```

Got undefined undefined from console. Why is this not working?

I also tried the following

```
let num_list = [2.99,5,6,3,2,4,5];
for (let num in num_list){
    console.log(num);
}
```

This time the output is index of each number:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

How should I fix this code?
Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: `for-in` loops over array indexes, not array elements.

Comment: You want to use `for (let student of students)`

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 0):

The type of loop you need is a `for... of` loop.

---

**Working Example:**

```js
let students = [
  {
    fname: "Jam",
    lname: "Brazier",
    snum: "0010",
  },

  {
    fname: "Ricardo",
    lname: "Allen",
    snum: "0020",
  }
]


for (let student of students) {
  console.log(student.fname);
}
```

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of